# regular expression for a text box that is not required, but needs to validate if entered

Tags: asp.net, regex

On my form I have a text box for a phone number. I have a regular expression that is fairly universal & can accept almost every variation for a phone number, local or international. the expression is as follows:

^((+)?[1-9]{1,2})?([-\s.])?(((\d{1,4}))|\d{1,4})(([-\s.])?[0-9]{1,12}){1,2}(x?[0-9]{1,})?$

The issue is, the field is not required, but needs to be validated if they decide to enter a number. is there any possible way of doing this?

Comment: Word of advise, regex'ing a phone number is a bad idea. How likely is it that it allows every possible "correct" phone number? Would it stop an input like "(333)-333-3333 ext. 999"? Because that's a totally valid number that fails in any regex looking to block alpha characters or periods. Unless your app is storing phone numbers to be auto-dialed by a machine later, then you don't REALLY need to require the user to enter the phone number in a machine-readable format.

Comment: @Graham i didn't design the app, im just a programmer. our clients are required to have at least 1 phone number registered with us in the database. the number is entered before the account is created, & all the info is reviewed by a human before the account is approved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround the entire regex, except the `^` and `$` with an extra `( )?`

```
^(((+)?[1-9]{1,2})?([-\s.])?(((\d{1,4}))|\d{1,4})(([-\s.])?[0-9]{1,12}){1,2}(x?[0-9]{1,})?)?$
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't do ASP programming, but couldn't you do some sort of condition that says something like:

```
if( textbox.value.length > 0 ) then validate
```

So it only validates if the user entered something